# How do I completely remove versions of Python I installed before I started using pyenv?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, uninstallation, linux-mint, pyenv

Firstly, I'm a relative beginner with Python, Linux, terminal and pyenv, so keep that in mind ;)

I learned that pyenv is a good way to manage multiple versions of Python in parallel between projects. Before I discovered that, I installed a couple versions of Python that I now would like to remove but I don't know how. I will reinstall them later using pyenv so everything's nice and neat.

I had a vague idea about which Python-versions I installed using `altinstall` in addition to the system: Python 3.7 and 3.9. My system (Linux Mint 20.1) came with Python 2.7 and 3.8 so I would like to leave those alone. Using the terminal command:

```
whereis python
```

I get the following output:

```
python: 
/usr/bin/python3.8 
/usr/bin/python2.7 
/usr/bin/python3.8-config 
/usr/lib/python3.8 
/usr/lib/python2.7 
/usr/lib/python3.9 
/etc/python3.8 
/etc/python2.7 
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 
/usr/local/bin/python3.9-config 
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 
/usr/local/bin/python3.7m 
/usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config 
/usr/local/lib/python3.8 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7 
/usr/local/lib/python3.9 
/usr/include/python3.8 
/usr/share/python
```

In conclusion, I would like to remove Python version 3.7 and 3.9 including related packages, without breaking my installation of Linux Mint 20.1, any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could type

```
python3.7 -c 'import site;print(site.getsitepackages())'
python3.9 -c 'import site;print(site.getsitepackages())'
```

to get all locations that may be deleted to uninstall those two versions.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up accepting a couple of old python versions floating around my system and have started using Pyenv regardless of those. The chance of my screwing up my OS was not worth the risk :)

Comment: @SWHJ Good choice.